# Django Admin: 'id' is not a callable or method of model?

Tags: django, django-admin

It's in the question. Why would my model not have the 'id' attribute? Isn't that created by default in Django?

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Risk, Impact


class RiskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','risk_title')



admin.site.register(Risk, RiskAdmin)
admin.site.register(Impact)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add 'id' to the list_display under my RiskAdmin section. However, I'm getting an error stating that 'id' is not an attribute of the model.

Comment: Yes, unless you specified another primary key, but the `id` is  *not* a callable or method, it is an attribute.

Comment: Please show the code where you used it

Comment: Daniel Roseman - my apologies I've added the code

Comment: Can you share the (relevant parts of the) `Risk` model?

Comment: Fixed, I accidentally labeled another primary key. SMH. Thanks!